# Each xtable produced in R-loops should have \begin{table}..\end{table} environment in Sweave

Tags: loops, knitr, xtable

I try to write an R-function which produces xtables in a loop. Later I want to call my function in a Sweave document- but a single chunk can't support multiple tables. I would have to put each table in a single chunk and wrap  it with the Latex Code ***\begin{table} ... \end{table}*.** 
So I wonder, whether it's possible to somehow call Sweave/knitr from within the Loop of the R-function and add ***\begin{table} .. \end{table}*** around each xtable?
Or whether it is somehow possible to send each xtable from the loop to a chunk with  ***\begin{table} ... \end{table}*** environment?

A mini-example of my function:

```
multiple_tables_Loop<-function(...){

(....) ##Some necessary calculations to produce a data frame

  for(j in 1:m){
    for(i in 1:n){

      a<-data.frame(...)   

      table<-xtable(a)

      print(table)
     } 
   }
 }
```

In Sweave I would call the function:

```
<<Hallo_Table,results='aisis'>>
 multiple_tables_Loop(...)
@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question. `xtable` does include `\begin{table}`/`\end{table}` pairs. And you can put multiple tables is a code chunk (for both Sweave and knitr `.Rnw` files). Could it be just that you have misspelled `'asis'` in your chunk header?

Showing `xtable` does include `\begin{table}`/`\end{table}`:

```
> xtable(data.frame(x=1))
% latex table generated in R 3.1.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Fri Jan 23 11:12:47 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And a simple `.Rnw` file of

```
<<results="asis">>=
library("xtable")
xtable(data.frame(x=1))
xtable(data.frame(y=1))
@
```

properly gives two tables.

If the misspelling isn't the problem, a complete minimally reproducible example is needed along with the version numbers of R and all the packages (output of `sessionInfo()`)